# Map Value to Specific Row and Column - Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set where i want to match the index row and change the value of a column within that row.

I have looked at map and loc and have been able to locate the data use df.loc but it filters that data down, all i want to do is change the value in a column on that row when that row is found.

What is the best approach - my original post can be found here:

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812417/float-slider-pandas-slider-to-adjust-value-in-csv-document)

It's simple to do in excel but struggling with Pandas.

Edit:

I have this so far which seems to work but it includes a lot of numbers after the total calculation along with dtype: int64

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\david\Documents\test.csv')

multiply = {2.1: df['Rate'] * df['Quantity']}

df['Total'] = df['Code'].map(multiply)

df.head()
```

how do i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

The pandas method [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) is likely a good option here. Mask takes two main arguments: a condition and something with which to replace values that meet that condition.

If you're trying to replace values with a formula that draws on values from multiple dataframe columns, you'll also want to pass in an additional axis argument.

**The condition**: this would be something like, for instance:

```
df['Code'] == 2.1
```

**The replacement value**: this can be a single value, a series/dataframe, or (most valuable for your purposes) a function/callable. For example:

```
df['Rate'] * df['Quantity']
```

**The axis**: Because you're passing a function/callable as the replacement argument, you need to tell `mask()` how to find those values. It might look something like this:

```
axis=0
```

So all together, the code would read like this:

```
df['Total'] = df['Code'].mask(
    df['Code'] == 2.1,
    df['Rate'] * df['Quantity'],
    axis=0
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help jeff really appreciated - it works however i noticed that my 2.2 code item also calculates total but it doesnt make sense - outputs 2.2 when it should be NaN

Comment: I've also noticed that when i change the boolean == 2.1 to 2.2 it does not affect line item 2.2?